# Картинки на сайт

Tags: html

Подскажите. Когда я скачиваю картинку для своего сайта, сохраняю, а затем вставляю в свой сайт, у меня заместо картинки показывает слово "изображение". Что делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проверьте разрешение, оно должно быть одинаковым в Вашем коде и в файле картинки, т.е. и там и там в одинаковом регистре, например gif gif

Comment: спасибо больщое